# MockServer with Undertow

Tags: java, undertow, apachebench

I am presently trying to create a mock server which generates a static json response (100KB) with a sleep of 200ms. I read the Json once from the disc at startup and store it in the instance variable as string and render the same for every request.

```
  public class Bot {

    private String json;

    public Bot() {
        InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("huge.json");
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(inputStreamReader);
            json = jsonObject.toJSONString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/endpoint")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response api(@QueryParam("sleep") String sleep) {

        if (sleep != null && !sleep.isEmpty() && Integer.valueOf(sleep) > 0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(Integer.valueOf(sleep));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        return Response.status(200).entity(json).build();
      }
  }
```

Also my undertow settings look something like this -

```
final Undertow.Builder builder = Undertow.builder()
            //.addHttpsListener("port", "0.0.0.0", sslContext)
            .addHttpListener(4080, "0.0.0.0")
            .setSocketOption(Options.SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_MODE, SslClientAuthMode.REQUESTED)
            .setSocketOption(Options.CONNECTION_LOW_WATER, 20000)
            .setSocketOption(Options.CONNECTION_HIGH_WATER, 21000)
            .setBufferSize(1024 * 16)
            .setIoThreads(Math.max(config.minIOThreads, Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() - 1))
            .setSocketOption(Options.BACKLOG, 2048)
            .setServerOption(UndertowOptions.ALWAYS_SET_DATE, true)
            .setServerOption(UndertowOptions.SSL_USER_CIPHER_SUITES_ORDER, true)
            .setServerOption(Options.SSL_ENABLED_CIPHER_SUITES, CIPHER_SUITES)
            .setHandler(Handlers.header(Handlers.path().addPrefixPath("/", getRestEasyServlet(config)),
                    Headers.SERVER_STRING, "Mock Server"))
            .setWorkerThreads(20000);

    undertow = builder.build();
    undertow.start();
```

I was running apache benchmark with a very basic minimal concurreny/thread of 1.

```
ab -t 9999 -k -n 10000 -c 1 host
```

I was expecting that there will be just 1 keep alive connection (worker thread will sleep for 200 ms and write the json to the connection and eventually the connection will be returned to the pool and the ab will reuse this connection to send the subsequent request) and I will get an rps of 5 considering i am putting a sleep of 200ms. However I noticed that a lot of pipes get created when i monitor the process sockets and eventually they max out with a TooManyFile open Exception.

I am not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: I am not sure whether the payload is so huge 100KB there is some problem with reusing the connection?

Comment: Also I do not see this issue when I change my json payload to a very small size. In that case the connections is reused and I see ab's result showing all requests with keep-alive.